# Can't clone/push via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Example:

```
$ git clone git@gitlab:carlos/test.git
Cloning into 'asd'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab port 22: No route to host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I added the IP and name to my hosts, but even if I use the IP directly, the error occurs.
I can login via SSH using root, it just doesn't work for git user.

I don't have idea of what is going on here.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe some kind of filter, as in http://askubuntu.com/a/136414/5470 and http://superuser.com/q/423852/141?

Comment: Try the [git URL section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is any of this. I can't clone via SSH, but I can login via SSH (using other user). I followed the gitlab instalation tutorial, and can't see what's wrong...

Comment: The only format your syntax seems to comply to would probably be git clone git@gitlab:/home/carlos/test.git but yet the error seems to be in the gitlab part of name handling.Can you ssh git@gitlab ?

Comment: No, I can't ssh git@gitlab... got the same no route to host error. If I use the IP instead: `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous! Connection to 10.80.5.183 closed.` Anyway, cloning using the IP gives me the same error as in the question.

Comment: So what ssh command give you a prompt? Smells like you have a network/connection/ssh server issue.

Comment: `ssh root@gitlab` gives me shell. Anything else gives me an error.

Comment: What do `gitlab` check and `gitlab-shell` check say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured gitlab-shell correctly?

```
cd /home/git/gitlab-shell
./bin/check
```

If the API access fails there's something wrong with your configuration.